# Doctrine: Check if any value in the db is a substring of input

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

I want to check if there is anything in the database that is a substring of a value, in this case $name.

I have checked [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions), but SUBSTRING requires me to set a start index as parameter.

LIKE with wildcards also doesn't seem to help, as it does exactly the opposite of what I want: it checks if the input is a substring of a db-value.

So what I want is to check if a db-value is a substring of the variable $name. So far I tried this:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('d')
    ->from('MyBundle:MyEntity', 'd')
    ->where(
        $qb->expr()->eq($qb->expr()->substring('d.name',1), ':name')
    )
    ->setParameter('name', $name);
```

But this is not quite it yet. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Why won't you use LIKE instead?

Answer (score 0):

There is LOCATE function in doctrine but I couldn't make it work so I think you can just use LIKE for such basic requirement.

```
public function findLeague($name)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l');
    $qb
        ->select('l')
        ->where($qb->expr()->like('l.name', ':name'))
        ->setParameter('name', '%' . $name . '%');

    $qb = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    return $qb;
}
```

It would return:

```
'1','Spanish Liga'
'3','German Bundes Liga'
'6','French Ligue One'
'7','Lig'
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not exactly what I want. Lets say $name = 'My Language'. Your example is checking if there is an l.name with at least $name in it, with both left and right wild cards; in other words results like 'This is My Language' will match. I want l.name to be a substring of $name, instead of $name being a substring of l.name.